# How run AviDemux in form of AppImage (universal binary) on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, avidemux, appimage

How run AviDemux in form of AppImage (universal binary) on Ubuntu 18.04 ?

```
$ ./avidemux_2.7.0.appImage
/tmp/.mount_bBzF8K/usr/bin/avidemux3_portable: error while loading shared libraries: libva-drm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as a workaround, try installing `libva-drm2` by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typing:

```
sudo apt install libva-drm2
```

If problem persists, then do:

```
cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.1
```

On condition that, if above-mentioned solutions did not work, as a last resort, install version 2.7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/avidemux
sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-qt avidemux2.6-plugins-qt
```

It will **avidemux 2.7** though it contains 2.6 in its name.

[Source](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/01/install-latest-avidemux-2-7-0-ubuntu-17-10-18-04/)

Comment: Your "install libva-drm2 + cp" workaround works. Thank you. Now AppImage launches without error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've downloaded the appimage file (this is not clear from your post), you first need to make the xxxx.appimage-file executable. This is done by right clicking and setting the properties to "executable".
From then on, you can right-click the xxx.appimage-file and run (or execute) it.
As far as I understand, an appimage-file contains ALL of the necessary compenents of the xxx-program, so it runs "on an island" so to speak.

Comment: Maybe it is not isolated island in this case :-) Existence of file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.1" makes the difference. Btw, "avidemux_2.7.0.appImage" file is downloaded from homepage, and executable mark is set.